# Grails Unidirectional Many to One and Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is there any way, to query (criteria) list of Many side with restrictions on one side in an Unidirectional many to one relationship

Domain

```
class Batch {

    String name
    Date date

}


class Record {
    String type
    Batch batch
}

class RecordDetails {
   String xx
   Record record
}
```

Is there anyway to criteria query all batch records, where batch.date = xx, and record.type = yy and recordDetails.xx = zz

HQL should work, but is there any other way with criteria other then in queries.

Comment: You probably can with Where queries, see the [More Advanced Subqueries in GORM section](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew24).

Comment: I am on grails 2.2.4, cant use it

Comment: Then only `sqlRestriction` comes to mind but you'd obviously have to write native SQL.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: Sure, see answer below..

Answer (score 1):

With Where queries and Detached criteria out of the question one option would be using `sqlRestriction` like so:

```
Batch.withCriteria {
    sqlRestriction """
        exists (
            select * from record r
            join record_details rd on rd.record_id = r.id 
            where 
                r.batch_id = {alias}.id and 
                r.type like ? and 
                rd.xx like ?
        )""", [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
}
```